# Неверное описание в Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

я тут столкнулся с проблемой неверного описание городов в гугл мапсе. Делаю запрос

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Москва&type=(cities)&key=123456
```

Тут всё окей, в теле ответа возвращается

```
"description": "Москва, город Москва, Россия",
```

Но когда я пытаюсь запросить это же описание

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Москва,+город+Москва,+Россия&type=(cities)&key=123456
```

То мне возращается

```
  "description": "город Москва, Москва, Россия",
```

Т.е. совершенно другой порядок. Может это я чего не понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всё правильно понимаете. Ошибки тут нет. У Google, как и у многих других реализован вероятносный движок. Т.е. вы задаёте вопрос вида: bBox ((lat, lon )x4шт) + query (string). Всё это улетает в некоторую модель, которая, вообще говоря, может очень сильно перекроить Ваш запрос (например, убрать окончания, написать слова в обратном порядке, часть слов выкинуть и т.п.). В результате, в зависимости от запроса, Вы можете получать очень неожиданные результат. Тонкости реализации движка, я думаю, знает очень узкий круг людей. При причины такого перестрояния кроятся именно в том, что я написал.

Что касается данного случая, то здесь ключом к решению может оказаться тот факт, что Google ищет точные совпадения. Найдя такое в [индексе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81), он формирует ответ, согласно количеству совпадений в индексе. Для большего понимания того, как это может происходить, прочтите о [TF-IDF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TF-IDF).